# Passing askyesno across an if/else split

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter

See this code snippet:

```
exclude = ["BURSAR", "SHOP"]
if any ((name in machineName for name in exclude)):
    question = askyesno('Warning', "That machine is on the exclude list. Are you sure you wish to continue?")
    if question == False:
        showinfo("No", "Cancelling action.")
    else:
        showinfo("Yes", "Continuing with Delprof...")
else:
    reply = subprocess.Popen(Command ...)
```

'machineName' is passed into it from above, then I need it to ask the question if machineName is in the exclude list, but give people the option, if they say Yes, to continue with the command.

How do I pass the code from clicking Yes thru the else: and run the command?

Thanks, Chris.

Comment: Is this in a function? If so, you can simply call `return` after the `showinfo("No", ...)` which prevents the rest of the function from being executed. You might even want to `return False`, so you can register if the function was aborted or not.

Comment: You could also replace your last `else` with `if question:`. If you do that you should initialize `question = True` before the first if.

Comment: @fhdrsdg, wouldn't that ask the question regardless of whether the name was in exclude or not?

Comment: No. As long as you keep the `if any(...):`, the question will only be asked when one of the names is in exclude

Comment: Thanks @fhdrsdg, that works nicely! Thank-you.

I'd mark as answered question if I could ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace your last else with `if question:`, the code after it will only run if `question` is `True`. If you do that you should initialize `question = True` before the first if.

```
exclude = ["BURSAR", "SHOP"]
question = True

if any ((name in machineName for name in exclude)):
    question = askyesno('Warning', "That machine is on the exclude list. Are you sure you wish to continue?")

    if question == False:
        showinfo("No", "Cancelling action.")
    else:
        showinfo("Yes", "Continuing with Delprof...")

if question:
    reply = subprocess.Popen(Command ...)
```